# Android: Can't call finish()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, activity-finish, system.exit

Why can't I call `finish()` in the code below?
I also can't start any Intent.

This is my code:

```
public class EditProfilePresenter<V extends EditProfileView> extends PickImagePresenter<V> {
    protected Profile profile;
    protected ProfileManager profileManager;

    protected EditProfilePresenter(Context context) {
        super(context);
        profileManager = ProfileManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void loadProfile() {
        ifViewAttached(BaseView::showProgress);
        profileManager.getProfileSingleValue(getCurrentUserId(), new OnObjectChangedListenerSimple<Profile>() {
            @Override
            public void onObjectChanged(Profile obj) {
                profile = obj;
                ifViewAttached(view -> {
                    if (profile != null) {
                        view.setName(profile.getUsername());
                        if (profile.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                            view.setProfilePhoto(profile.getPhotoUrl());
                        }
                    }
                    view.hideProgress();
                    view.setNameError(null);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void attemptCreateProfile(Uri imageUri) {
        if (checkInternetConnection()) {
            ifViewAttached(view -> {
                view.setNameError(null);
                String name = view.getNameText().trim();
                boolean cancel = false;
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    view.setNameError(context.getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                    cancel = true;
                } else if (!ValidationUtil.isNameValid(name)) {
                    view.setNameError(context.getString(R.string.error_profile_name_length));
                    cancel = true;
                }
                if (!cancel) {
                    view.showProgress();
                    profile.setUsername(name);
                    createOrUpdateProfile(imageUri);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void createOrUpdateProfile(Uri imageUri) {
        profileManager.createOrUpdateProfile(profile, imageUri, (boolean success) -> {
            ifViewAttached(view -> {
                view.hideProgress();
                if (success) {
                    onProfileUpdatedSuccessfully();
                    // ----- HERE -----
                    System.exit(0);
                    // I can't call finish(), but can call System.exit().
                } else {
                    view.showSnackBar(R.string.error_fail_create_profile);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    protected void onProfileUpdatedSuccessfully() {
        ifViewAttached(BaseView::finish);
    }
}
```

Starting an Intent to send the user back to the LoginActivity (which will check whether there is a user) would be the best solution, but the problem is that I can't start an Intent (it says: "cannot resolve constructor").

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: thanks for pointing that, eng. is not my mother language and I know I have lots of mistakes in that.

Comment: You can only call `finish()` on an `Activity`. The code you posted is not an `Activity`.

Comment: @DavidWasser Looks like the answer - may as well post it as such for future users.

Comment: i know that my friend, my question is how to loop it to make finish after the activity in the UP POST finished?

Comment: @AmerAnajjem You can add an attribute `public Activity myActivity;` and then call `myActivity.finish()`. Keep in mind that you still have to set the attribute in your activity like this: `myEditProfilePresenter.myActivity = this;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only call `finish()` on an `Activity`. The code you posted is not an `Activity`.